# IE7 don't apply font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I am trying to add font for displaying currency sign (Russian rouble). Code that I am using taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/). Also i added magic `zoom: 1;`. But it don't work.

Font-face defenition

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Rouble";
    src: url('/catalog/view/font/rouble.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/catalog/view/font/rouble.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/catalog/view/font/rouble.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/catalog/view/font/rouble.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/catalog/view/font/rouble.svg#Rouble') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Then usage

```
.rubl {
    font-family: "Rouble";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

I test it with ie7 from Win Vista under WM VirtualBox [taken from here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) (if it is matter).

What am I doing wrong?

Live example you can see [here](http://safekeeping.dev4fun.ru/safes/mebelnye/) (Login/Password: demo/demo)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665622/russian-ruble-symbol-html-code By all accounts, you would be better off using an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing on IE 11 in IE 7 mode, the console shows an error with code CSS3111, referring to rouble.eot, with additional data “terminating; too few slides: 0”. Looks a bit odd, but apparently the EOT file is corrupt. The same problem appears in EOT mode, whereas IE 9 and newer use the WOFF file.

Quite apart from this, the page uses font trickery rather than a proper approach: the HTML markup has `<span class="rubl">  a</span>`, and CSS settings are used in an attempt at making the browser misreprsent the letter “a” as the ruble sign. This trickery works since the font claims that the ruble sign is a glyph for the letter “a”.

Comment: So problem was in `.eot` file. Now my problem is solved, thanks! And yes, i know what the point of the trick, in this font all letters is varieties of letter "Р"