# Ruble ( ₽ ) symbol not showing on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, currency, symbols

I am developing an eCommerce application and one of the features is that users can choose their currencies. Now, I noticed that when somebody selects the Russian Ruble, the symbol shows as just a square in Chrome on iOS (version 7.1). Why is that?

It should show this:

```
₽
```

but it shows this:

```
▢
```

Note that I am using the HTML code to display it:

```
&#x20bd;
```

On the desktop version (iMac) it shows fine and I imagine on other operating systems, too.

Anybody got a clue why it's not showing in iOS?

Comment: Where exactly do you display it? In a `UIWebView`? Or in a `UILabel` or `UITextView`/`UITextField`?

Comment: fun fact, although this question was asked 5 years ago, Apple messed up the rouble symbol in 2020 with iOS13, lol. It's gone again. Here's the fix https://medium.com/@rooman_v/ios-13-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F-5cba666f7ae5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruble symbol supports only iOS 8+.

The Unicode consortium officially designated a code point, U+20BD RUBLE SIGN, ₽, for the new symbol in Unicode 7.0, released 2014-06-16. iOS7 was released earlier. [Last entry in this Unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf)

Comment: You could improve your answer, for example by citing some official sources.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given is correct (the symbol was only recently introduced) but there is some really good detailed information on this issue over here: [Russian ruble symbol HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665622/russian-ruble-symbol-html-code)