# Safari iOS not rendering ₽ symbol in input field

Tags: ios, input, safari, mobile-safari

I have a problem with the input field in Safari browser on iOS devices.
Ruble currency symbol rendered as an empty square with black borders.
Problem occurs only on input fields, but in all other DOM elements symbol is rendered normally.

Here how it looks:
[image]

P.S. $ sign works normally

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146762/7167839?

Comment: Don't see how it helps me, everywhere else symbol is working, but the input field is bugged in safari (only on iOS)

Comment: You mean that the field under `Желаемая сумма` is an input field? So it is kinda tappable and brings keyboard up?

Comment: Yes, it's input field controlled by Vue model binding.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> On 4 February 2014, the Unicode Technical Committee during its 138th
>   meeting in San Jose accepted U+20BD ₽ ruble sign symbol for the
>   Unicode version 7.0, the symbol was then included into Unicode 7.0
>   released on 16 June 2014.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_ruble#Currency_symbol

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but how would it help in my case?

Comment: Most of the time, the reason is a wrong formatting. You should check if you are using the correct symbol for rendering.

Comment: But those symbols are identical, however, in input field it's rendered as black square. Maybe it's the bug with the safari input field not showing ruble symbol correctly?