# What HTML character reserved for missing char?

Tags: html, special-characters

I faced a problem where I need to replace missing char with abbreviation. 
The missing character I am talking about looks like an empty square and it get displayed if this character sign is not recognized.

Happened to me when using new RUBLE sign on older devices, where this char is not present in registry.

Answer (score 1):

Type this after `<html>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: It's not the problem of encoding, it's a problem of device. This char was added to the registry only in 2014, so older devices simply can't recognize it. So I need to replace what ever they got displayed instead of it. And API is serving it as a sign not an HTML entity, like that  ₽ and those devices just show blank square, I need to know how to replace it, what HTML entity to target for replace

Comment: Can you tell as what device is it?

Comment: Let me know what device is it, run into bit of a problem when I was doing a webpage in Serbian Cyrillic a long time ago.

Comment: It's an iPhone4 basically

Comment: :) well here is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665622/russian-ruble-symbol-html-code, way back in a day I had to use encoding ISO-something-something to get Serbian Cyrillic to work.